# Change bell sound back to 18.04 version

Tags: gnome, sound, teminal-bell, terminal-bell

Today, I have updated my Ubuntu 18.04 machine to 20.04. I have noticed that the bell/alert sound has changed. I personally much preferred the old bell sound (used at least in 18.04 and I think also in 16.04) and would like to change it back if possible.

I am already aware of the 'Alert sound' section of the 'Sound' page in Settings. This only allows me to choose between five different options (Default, Bark, Drip, Glass and Sonar). None is the one I want.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Sound' page in Gnome Settings; showing (amongst other things) a five-choice menu for the alert sound]

EDIT: I've already located the old bell sound on the computer (it's still in the files, at `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg`), so now I only need to know how to set a custom alert sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not using gnome, but you can do like this:
Open the directory where it has alerts sounds `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts` (not sure about directory) as root and replace a sound file (for example `glass.ogg`) with a that one you want. Reboot your system and than choose `Glass` in sound settings.